# How to add in-app purchase in ios app where the purchased item needs to be available for the users of our web, android application?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an iOS application which needs to have in-app purchase support, but the problem in adding in-app purchase is that the same user should have the ability to use the purchase to access his/her purchased content in our web portal and also in our Android application.

Vice versa, we need to make the content which was being purchased in the web portal or Android app to be accessible in iOS application.

Is there a tweak to do this?

Comment: You could store a user object (with bought contents) on the server and request and set that object from every application

Answer (score 3):

"Is there a tweak to do this?" - No. You'll need a server to manage your purchases independently of any of the platforms' purchase systems.

**Example:** When a client makes a purchase via Apple IAP, the client sends the receipt to the [server to be validated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) and, if successful, your server will note that that this client has purchased something in your system. Subsequently when the user is using your web portal, or another device/platform, it is ***your server*** that will make available their purchases.

See [Apple's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Store userCanPurchase items for each user

```
NSSet *userCanPurchase = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"productID1", @"productID2", nil];
SKProductRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:userCanPurchase];
productRequest.delegate = self;
[productRequest start];
```